# Change a long table to wide table

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a long table like this:

```
A <- rep(c("a","b","c","d"),each=4)
B <- rep(c("e","f","g","h"),4)
C <- rep(c("i","j"),8)
D <- rnorm(16)
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
head(df)

   A  B  C        D
1  a  e  i  -0.18984508
2  a  f  j  -1.82703822
3  a  g  i  -0.17307580
4  a  h  j  -1.38104238
5  b  e  i   0.08699983
6  b  f  j  -0.36442461
```

I would like to change to long table to a wide format so that each element in column A and B is a title of a column. Each row should be a 1 or 0 indicating if elements exists. Column C and D remains the same. The desired table is something like this:

```
C           D a b e f g h
i -0.18984508 1 0 1 0 0 0
j -1.82703822 1 0 0 1 0 0
i -0.17307580 1 0 0 0 1 0
j -1.38104238 1 0 0 0 0 1
i  0.08699983 0 1 1 0 0 0
j -0.36442461 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a form of reshaping which can be done with the `reshape2` package.

```
library("reshape2")
dcast(melt(df, id.vars=c("C", "D")), C+D~value, fun.aggregate=length)
```

which gives

```
   C           D a b c d e f g h
1  i -1.44485242 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
2  i -0.80834639 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
3  i -0.15202085 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
4  i -0.05626233 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
5  i  0.12031754 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
6  i  0.62206658 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
7  i  0.77101891 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
8  i  1.38752097 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
9  j -2.52137154 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
10 j -0.53231537 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
11 j -0.30178539 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
12 j -0.29823112 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
13 j -0.12988540 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
14 j  0.00517754 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
15 j  0.51452289 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
16 j  0.53260223 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

The order is not the same as the original data set, but if that is important put an order column in, carry it through, and then sort on it at the end.